# Is there a way to version client proxy generated with svcutil?

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a WCF service. I generate proxy code using a svcutil like

`svcutil.exe <wsdl & xsd files> /serializer:XmlSerializer /targetClientVersion:Version35 /namespace:*,<namespace> /noconfig /out:GeneratedProxy.cs`

and distribute the `GeneratedProxy.cs` proxy file, as well as the wsdl & xsd files to partners that use my service. They then use my proxy in their client applications to consume my service.

I am looking for a way to add versioning info (something very simple like YYYY-MM format) to the generated proxy file, so that when client applications call into my service using the provided `GeneratedProxy.cs` file, I have visibility on which proxy, that I provided, they are using on the server side (preferably through headers). I want clients to be unaware of all this -- they use the provided `GeneratedProxy.cs` file and the versioning info is automatically sent to the server.

I looked into using `IClientMessageInspector` but that doesn't solve my problem. It requires my partners to make modifications to their client applications to register the wcf "behavior". And I would have to depend on them to correctly populate the http headers.

(It is also acceptable to me if the versioning info is based on the current xsd data contract and wsdl file)

Comment: Do you want to use the version information to find out which client called your service? If this is the case, we need to modify the proxy class of each client to inform the server of its version information when calling the WCF service.

Comment: We put out new proxies regularly. We want a way to know which proxy is being currently used by calling clients ie. the latest proxy we put out, or an old proxy. Does this make sense? So modifying the proxy class is the only way? I am not sure if this is a good solution for us since it is not automated as we like.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense. The client's proxy is just an interface, it does not contain the implementation of methods.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy that you provide to your clients is just a proxy.
They don't have to use it to access your service, they can create their own class to call it.

This means you can't know how they call your service.

You can ask for additional parameters in the request, like "callingApplication" or "proxyVersion" to be passed by the caller, but the truth of the values is not guaranteed...

(+) And a side note: Proxy should not be updated frequently. You need to plan and design your service, in terms of requests and responses, and ideally generate the Proxy once, then updating the implementations should not affect the request / response structures